# Ensuring integrity over 2 databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, transactions, transactionscope

So, I have two databases... the Users database and another database that also contains a Users table. Both have an email field. I'd like to update both email fields at the same time.

The (simplified) code looks something like this:

```
using(var db1 = new Db1Context())
using(var db2 = new Db2Context())
{
    db1.Users.Single(u => u.Email == oldEmail).Email = someEmail;
    db2.Users.Single(u => u.Email == oldEmail).Email = someEmail;
    db1.SaveChanges();
    db2.SaveChanges(); //what if this fails?
}
```

So, attempt 1:

```
using(var db1 = new Db1Context())
using(var db2 = new Db2Context())
using(var txs = new TransactionScope())
{
    db1.Users.Single(u => u.Email == oldEmail).Email = someEmail;
    db2.Users.Single(u => u.Email == oldEmail).Email = someEmail;
    db1.SaveChanges();
    db2.SaveChanges(); //what if this fails?
    txs.Complete();
}
```

fails with an `ArgumentException` and the following stacktrace:

```
[ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.]
   System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ConnectToProxy(String nodeName, Guid resourceManagerIdentifier, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Boolean& nodeNameMatches, UInt32& whereaboutsSize, CoTaskMemHandle& whereaboutsBuffer, IResourceManagerShim& resourceManagerShim) +0
   System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize() +155
   System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.get_ProxyShimFactory() +76
   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken) +160
   System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx) +78
...[etc...]
```

As we understand things, this is because [Azure does not support distributed transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16676979/14357).

So now, instead, we try to use SqlTransactions:

```
using(var db1 = new Db1Context())
using(var db2 = new Db2Context())
{
    if(db1.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        //transaction can only work on open connection
        db1.Database.Connection.Open(); 
    }
    using(var tx = db1.Database.Connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //ArgumentException on next line
        db1.Users.Single(u => u.Email == oldEmail).Email = someEmail;
        db2.Users.Single(u => u.Email == oldEmail).Email = someEmail;
        db1.SaveChanges();
        db2.SaveChanges(); //what if this fails?
    }
}
```

This fails with an error:

> ArgumentException: "EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection."

So how can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't. You need to implement 2PC to support this. Sounds like Azure has some very severe limitations.